# script function not working inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load data from a page on clicking to an element in a page. the page data includes a slider (flexslider).but the code is not working.
I tried this code:

```
$("#works .work").click(function () {
    var projectUrl = $(this).attr("data-url");
    $.ajax({
        url: projectUrl
    }).success(function (data) {
        $(".works .preview").fadeIn("fast");
        $(".works .preview").load(projectUrl);
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(".works .preview").offset().top - 70
        }, 500);
        $("#slider").flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: true,
            directionNav: false,
            controlNav: true,
            animationSpeed: 600
        });
    });
    return false
});
```

everything except slider works perfectly.

when I put the code in console it works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly.

Try this

```
$("#works .work").click(function () {
    var projectUrl = $(this).attr("data-url");
    $(".works .preview").load(projectUrl, function (data) {
        $(".works .preview").fadeIn("fast");
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(".works .preview").offset().top - 70
        }, 500);
        $("#slider").flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: true,
            directionNav: false,
            controlNav: true,
            animationSpeed: 600
        });
    });     
    return false
});
```

You are using `$(".works .preview").load(projectUrl)` where load will execute asynchronously.

Instead of

```
$(".works .preview").load(projectUrl);
```

use

```
$(".works .preview").html(data);
```

Comment: i tried that...but not working...when i tried that nothing is showing

Comment: @user3636263 Syntax is `jQuery - load( url, data, callback ) `

Comment: i need something like this
 <div class="work one-third column" data-url="project-image.php?name=projectname"> is that possible??

Comment: @user3636263, Yes thats possible, use as given in the answer